# Problema com float css

Tags: css, float

Gente criei esse código abaixo para simular o mesmo problema em um site que estou desenvolvendo para praticar meu html e css.
Tenho dois elemento que flutuam para esquerda e um para a direita mas quando limpo o float do segundo elemento o terceiro elemento(direita) é empurrado para baixo.
como resolvo isso?
**html:**

```
<div class="primeiro"></div>
<div class="segundo"></div>
<div class="terceiro"></div>



**css:**
    div{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: pink;
    border: 2px solid black;
    }

.primeiro{
  float: left;
}

.segundo{
 float: left;
 clear: left;
}

.terceiro{
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: O terceiro vem depois do segundo, logo ele vai ficar na mesma linha do segundo. Vc queria que o terceiro ficasse na mesma linha do primeiro?

Comment: blz....não sabia que elementos flutuantes respeitavam hierarquia... valew

Comment: Cara, nesse caso não é nem hierarquia, é o flow dos elementos mesmo. Eles são irmãos, não tem hierarquia. Pelo menos entendo hierarquia como pai e filhos, uma árvore.

Comment: A resposta não atendeu? Há algum problema? Por favor, questione ou marque ✔️ para dar a pergunta como resolvida. Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Os elementos obedecem a fluidez onde eles estão dispostos. A terceira `div` estará sempre ao lado da segunda com `float: right`.

Colocando `clear: left` na segunda `div`, você está dizendo que nada poderá estar ao lado esquerdo dessa `div`, logo ela irá ficar abaixo da primeira, e a terceira ficará na mesma linha da segunda, mas do lado direito.

Não é nem uma questão de hierarquia, já que os elementos são irmãos. As 3 `div`s estão na mesma hierarquia. Apenas a segunda `div` poderia ficar na mesma linha da primeira com `float: right`, já que ela é o elemento seguinte.

No seu caso, a terceira `div` vai ficar na mesma linha da segunda, por ser o elemento seguinte.